# cp command which partially resolves symlinks

Tags: backup, symlink, cp, file-copy

Is there an easy way to copy a directory recursively where
symlinks to external files/directories are resolved (target file is copied),
but internal symlinks (pointing to files inside the copied tree) are kept?

Example:

```
touch outsidefile
mkdir src
ln -s ../outsidefile src/sym1
touch src/insidefile
ln -s insidefile src/sym2
cp [???] src dest # or other command
```

wanted result:

```
$ ls dest
 insidefile
 sym1
 sym2 -> insidefile
```

i.e. `sym1` is a regular file, `sym2` keeps to be a symlink.

Answer (score 5):

```
rsync -a --copy-unsafe-links src/ dest
```

From the `man` page:

> **--copy-unsafe-links**
>
> This tells rsync to copy the referent of symbolic links that point outside the copied tree.  Absolute symlinks are also treated like ordinary
>                 files,  and  so are any symlinks in the source path itself when `--relative` is used.  This option has no additional effect if `--copy-links` was also specified.
>
> [...]
>
> **--links --copy-unsafe-links**
>                 Turn all unsafe symlinks into files and duplicate all safe symlinks.

Comment: Hmm. Possibly add the `-l` option? I misread the manpage initially, exchanging `-l` for `--copy-links`.

Comment: @jofel, you need a trailing / on src in addition to -l as per edit.

Comment: From my experience ```rsync``` and symlink behavior is very tricky. I can't remember exactly how, but it even makes a difference whether you add the slash at the end of a folder or not.

Comment: @Tom, Sorry, my bad, I replaced -r with -a in my edit, but forgot to remove -l since as -a implies -l. I'll let you fix the mess as you see fittest since it's your answer. You may want to mention running `symlinks -cs src` beforehand to fix the absolute links and relative symlinks like ../src/inside that do point inside.

Comment: I don't think `-al` breaks anything, but replaced with just `-a`. I don't have `symlinks` by default on my system, so don't know about that. I also don't know how `rsync` determines unsafe or not; I would have expected it to resolve links fully and leave them alone if they do point inside the tree, but haven't tested that.